# Guess a natural object

Tags: riddle, knowledge

Thousands of lines, thousands of lines, can't be seen when dropped in the water, all things grow with me, all of them laugh in their hearts. (guess a natural object)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my guess:

> SALT

Thousands of lines,

> "Throughout history, salt... has been such an important element of life that it has been the subject of many stories, fables, folktales and fairy tales." [source](https://seasalt.com/salt-101/about-salt/history-of-salt). It is discussed in the Bible, in ancient Chinese writings, in medieval books, and on and on. Thousands of lines have been written about salt.

thousands of lines,

> The salt trade has been a major industry throughout history. Trade lines in salt span the globe. Demand for salt has been a factor in wars, migrations, and revolutions.

can't be seen when dropped in the water,

> Salt dissolves in water, separating into Na and Cl ions

all things grow with me,

> Salt is [essential for life on Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_in_biology). It is a critical nutrient for animals and plants need a small amount of salinity to survive.

all of them laugh in their hearts.

> In the body, salt is used to maintain fluid levels such as blood and tears, and support muscles and nerves. So it has a connection to both laughter and the heart - but I am not sure on this one.

(guess a natural object)

> Okay - I guess this natural object: "gues**S** **A** natura**L** objec**T**"

Comment: Great answer +1